# Could not resolve legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0)

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, java-resources

i get this error when i want to build android studio project

mergeDebugJavaResource
Could not resolve legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.jar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0)

my gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.i_e_commerce.Moodlia"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
//    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.kovachcode:timePickerWithSeconds:1.0.1'
    implementation 'io.github.ShawnLin013:number-picker:2.4.13'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
}
```

I checked different versions but it didn't solve it, I tried to fix it with VPN but it didn't work

please help me to find out the problem and solve it.

Comment: Try remove this dependency: 

    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.6.2'

This library doesnt using AndroidX yet, try run your project withou its.